# Remover valores duplicados en foreach PHP obtenidos por JSON

Tags: php, json

Estoy obteniendo datos de una API utilizando json. Lo que deseo es que los valores de country no se repitan. Obtiene datos de nombres de universidades, país, estado, url. Lo que quiero es que dentro del `select` en las etiquetas `option` se puedan ver todas los paises disponibles.

Les dejo el código:

```
<?php 
    $pais ='';
    $json = file_get_contents("http://universities.hipolabs.com/search?country=".$pais);
    $arreglo = json_decode($json,"false");
?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS v5.0.2 -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"  integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

  </head>
  <body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <div class="container">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">API Universidad</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler d-lg-none" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapsibleNavId" aria-controls="collapsibleNavId"
              aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavId">
              <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
                  <li class="nav-item active">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="visually-hidden">(current)</span></a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                  </li>
              </ul>
          </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="container">
        <div class="mb-3">
          <label class="form-label"></label>
          <select class="form-control">
            <?php
            foreach($arreglo as $post){
                echo "<option>". $post['country']."</option>";
            }
            ?>
          </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Así es como se ve al obtener los datos json

[image: Captura]

Agradezco cualquier ayuda.

Comment: Hola, podrías hacer un arreglo en el cual vayas insertando cada país en el foreach y ya solo sería consultar dicho arreglo y en caso de que el arreglo contenga el país simplemente lo omites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **Respuesta editada:**

Después de varias pruebas de velocidad con distintas funciones de matrices que he probado, la que mejor parece funcionar es la siguiente:

```
$arreglo = json_decode($json,"false");
for ($i = 0; count($arreglo) > $i; $i++) {
    if (!isset($countries[$arreglo[$i]['country']])) {
        $countries[$arreglo[$i]['country']] = 1;
    }
}
$countries = array_keys($countries);
```

En terminar el bucle esta tarda unos *0,005* segundos, y la anterior con `array_reduce` *0,175* segundos aproximadamente (y con `in_array` tardaba *0,030* segundos). En total hay más de *9.000* registros en el json descargado.

**Funcionamiento:**

1. Al ser una matriz multidimensional recorremos los elementos de la matriz `$arreglo` mediante un bucle `for` donde le decimos que hará un total de iteraciones igual al número total de elementos de la matriz, dato que conseguimos saber mediante `count($arreglo)`.
2. Para evitar duplicar el valor de país, en cada iteración comprobamos si existe la clave de pais en una matriz llamada `$countries` mediante un `!isset`.
3. En caso que no exista la agregamos a la matriz `$countries` asignándole un valor simbólico de 1 (que luego desecharemos)
4. Y así hasta terminar las iteraciones. Esto nos habra creado una matriz similar a esta:

   ```
   $countries = [
     [pais1 => 1]
     [pais2 => 1]
     [pais3 => 1]
     ...
   ];
   ```
5. Ahora solo queda generar una nueva matriz que contenga solo los valores de los paises, y para ello extraemos solamente las claves de `$countries` mediante la función `array_keys` y ya la tenemos lista para generar los `<option>` del `<select>` de paises.

---

Prueba con esto, seguramente se puede mejorar, pero a mi me da resultado:

En la parte de arriba pon esto despues de decodificar el $json:

```
$arreglo = json_decode($json,"false");
$countries = array_reduce($arreglo, function($accumulator, $item) {
    $accumulator[$item['country']][] = 1;
    return $accumulator;
}, []);
$countries = array_keys($countries);
```

Y cambiar el foreach por esto:

```
    <?php
    foreach($countries as $post){
        echo "<option>". $post."</option>";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: muchas gracias funciono perfectamente.

Comment: Me alegro, luego lo documento un poco para la comunidad y para ti tambien. Y si mientras descubro alguna otra forma mejor tambien lo pondre. Estate atento a los cambios por si acaso :-)

Comment: Genial me parece perfecto @masterguru igual este código lo subiré a github ya que siempre dejo scripts en PHP para la comunidad y para la gente que desee aprender. Aunque a mi me falta mucho por mejorar.

Comment: @JoaqhoC Ya he actualizado la respuesta y efectivamente habia otra forma mucho mas rapida que deberias mirarte y usar en lugar de la primera.

Comment: Genial @masterguru ahora lo chequeo muchas gracias!.

Comment: @JoaqhoC Por cierto, he mirado tambien tu otra peticion y ya la tengo hecha, pero no puedo responderte porque seguramente te cerraran la pregunta porque no has intentado nada y solo pides que te la hagan (la he hecho por diversion basicamente, ha sido un ejercicio para mi)

Comment: si, es lo mas probable. Igual forma ya he buscado info en google y eh tratado de buscar una solución lo mas efectiva, pero arroja errores :/.

Comment: @JoaqhoC: pues edita tu pregunta añadiendo los intentos que has hecho con Ajax y asi podre responderte, aunque no te hayn salido bien

Comment: ya lo edite y sigo haciendo intentos pero sin resultados.

Comment: @JoaqhoC Es que no tienes instalado el jquery veo, pero vas bien... si vuelves a editar la pregunta cambiando lo del array_reduce por lo del for que he puesto aqui me pongo a responderte

Comment: Ahí pude agregar el jquery y actualice con el array que me has compartido